# Drupal 6 page and form custom module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'd like to make a drupal page with a form. Something like the following, which doesn't render:

```
function score_table_menu() {

  $items['table'] = array(
    'title' => t('name'),
    'page arguments' => array('table_page'),
    'page arguments' => array('table_form'),
    'description' => t('score table'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

  );
  return $items;
}

function table_page(){
$output .= t('Complicated Hello');
$header = stuff;
$rows = stuff;
$output .= theme_table($header, $rows);
return $output;
}

function table_form(){

$stuff_array = array (values);
$form['choice']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select Stuff'),
    '#options' => $stuff_array,
  );


  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );
    return $form;

}

function table_form_validate(){}

function table_form_submit(){
drupal_set_message(t('Submitted'));
}
```

Is it possible to have half the module render a page and the other half a form? I've written out two page arguments. I don't see any difference between page argument and callback. Also might need to use drupal_get_form() to render the form on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
page callback
```

is the function that you want this URI to trigger.

```
page arguments
```

are any arguments that you want to sent to that function when the callback is called.

Your menu item should look like this:

```
$items['table'] = array(
  'title' => t('name'),
  'page callback' => 'table_page',
  'description' => t('score table'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Or this:

```
$items['table'] = array(
  'title' => t('name'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('table_form'),
  'description' => t('score table'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

In your table_form, you can use other form types to display markup,

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => theme_table($header, $rows),
);
```

Take a look in the API for a better understanding of hook_menu: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6

Comment: Does '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => theme_table($header, $rows),  work for drupal 6?  Does your answer address how to have half a page and half a form?

Comment: ok simple edit, #markup should actually be #value in drupal 6